# Is there a way to mix these memory modules?

Tags: memory, bios, hardware-compatibility, dmidecode, lshw

I'm trying to mix two 4Gb DDR3 modules from G.Skill with another two 4Gb DDR3 from a generic Chinese brand called Ankowall.

The BIOS detects all modules and automatically clocks them at 1333MHz but neither 64bit (Linux & Windows 10) nor memtest 86+ detect the 16Gb, only 8Gb.

I've tried all combinations, testing each module and any combination of them in each slot.

I've tried mixing a G.Skill module with an Ankowall module. They are compatible between different brands and the OSes detect the 8Gb no problem, clocking the modules at 1333MHz with no problems. But as soon as I plug another two modules the OSes don't detect more than 8Gb in any combination.

So the problem seems to be with quad channel configuration maybe?

I've also tried to force 1333MHz and 1066MHz in the BIOS, setting the memory voltage, the primary timings and secondary timings to no avail. Checked all the timings were correct in HWInfo64. I haven't tweaked the CPU values in the BIOS

My CPU: [INTEL i7-2600K](https://anonym.to/?https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52214/intel-core-i7-2600k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html)
My mobo:[ASUS Maximus IV ExtremeZ](https://anonym.to/?https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/MAXIMUS_IV_EXTREMEZ/specifications/)
Mem: [Ankowall modules](http://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_dWFRuCq)

Here's the output of two memory diagnostics commands:

```
dmidecode -t memory
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0060, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: 0x0062
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x005F, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0060
    Error Information Handle: 0x0064
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 0080
    Serial Number: 7A0F265B
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: ANKOWALL          
    Rank: 2

Handle 0x0061, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0060
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 04CD
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: F3-17600CL9-4GBXLD
    Rank: 2

Handle 0x0066, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0060
    Error Information Handle: 0x0065
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 0080
    Serial Number: 7A0F265A
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: ANKOWALL          
    Rank: 2

Handle 0x0068, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0060
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 04CD
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: F3-17600CL9-4GBXLD
    Rank: 2
```

And

```
lshw -class memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 3603
       date: 11/09/2012
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2 DISABLED
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: internal unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 60
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns) [empty]
          product: ANKOWALL
          vendor: 0080
          physical id: 0
          serial: 7A0F265B
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
          product: F3-17600CL9-4GBXLD
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns) [empty]
          product: ANKOWALL
          vendor: 0080
          physical id: 2
          serial: 7A0F265A
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
          product: F3-17600CL9-4GBXLD
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

Comment: The output you pasted shows you are mixing manufacturers within each channel.

Comment: @D.SM I have two G.Skill modules in DIMM1 and 2 and the Ankowall modules in DIMM3 and 4. Also I tried to use only a G.Skill module in DIMM1 and an Ankowall in DIMM2 and they were perfectly compatible. My PC detected both modules with a total of 8Gb in dual channel. When I go for the 4 modules in quad channel is where the problems start.

Comment: Switch one of the gskills with one of the ankowalls, report the results.

Comment: Also, neither your cpu nor your mainboard support quad channel operation.

Comment: True, thanks for the observation. Despite this it should support up to 32Gb at 2200MHz and below in dual channel configuration so 16Gb populating its 4 DIMMs with four 4Gb modules should have no problems. Especially when I mixed two 4Gb modules of each brand and the OSes recognized them correctly. I tried every combination with each module in each DIMM and it all work perfectly when it's only 8Gb total memory. Above that no matter what combination of modules I choose, it only recognizes 8Gb total memory. Do you want me to post the result dmidecode and lshw also?

Comment: The output you posted says you mixed manufacturers on each channel. I don't know if you tried booting the system with each channel containing sticks from a single manufacturer, since you haven't provided output proving so.

Comment: I only have two Ankowall modules and two from G.Skill so I can't populate all four with a single manufacturer unfortunately. When I populate just two with a single manufacturer or mixing them it works well and the OSes detect them. I've also tried populating both DIMM1 and 2 or DIMM3 and 4 with two modules (single and mixed) and it works perfectly. The problems appear only with the 4 DIMMs populated.